# Ajax Control toolkit not working when website is published

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have website published and with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and Ajax control toolkit features on the page.

However, when running same, the ajax controls are not working. Am not getting any error on the browser
Here below is my webconfig file

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name=xxx"" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxx;Initial Catalog=Audit_Data;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

```
  <system.web>
<!--<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="480" />-->
   <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>

<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<pages enableEventValidation ="false">

</pages>
```

```
      <appSettings>
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
```

Anyone can help me out of it.

thanks

Comment: did you find any errors in browser console?

Comment: @webruster no error in the browser console

Comment: then what is your screen look alike

Comment: @Webruster nothing is being displayed.. am trying the ModalPopupExtender in asp.net..

Comment: try to change   the `ScriptManager` in the page from `<asp:ScriptManager>` to `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager>`